# Save HTML to database and later add PHP links

Tags: php, html

Hello i am storing html into database.

Next i am querying results with codeIgniter

```
<?php echo($lekcija[0]->tekst);?>
```

Problem is in my html i have images and i wanna for src and php created link

```
<img src="/images/mysql-kako-instalirati-mysql.JPG" alt="Kako instalirati MySQL ?">
```

Something like this

```
   <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/images/mysql-kako-instalirati-mysql.JPG" alt="Kako instalirati MySQL ?">
```

But i have problem php is rendered as HTML any idea how to override this?

Comment: Do not store HTML in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use a place holder and than replace it when you serve the page, example:

```
<img src="{BASE_URL}/images/mysql..." alt="..." />
```

All you have to do is replace `{BASE_URL}` with whatever code you want in place of it using a PHP replace function or whatever you prefer at that point.

Comment: wierd example something better

Comment: What's weird about it? You use placeholders and replace them with the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

Why not following the good practise as suggested..

```
echo img(array('src'=>'/images/mysql-kako-instalirati-mysql.JPG', 'alt'=> 'Kako instalirati MySQL ?'));
```

If you have the image path in `$lekcija[0]->tekst` ?

then it would be

```
echo img(array('src'=>'/images/'.$lekcija[0]->tekst, 'alt'=> 'Kako instalirati MySQL ?'));
```

Learn more about Codeigniter helper from [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img)